# PHP FTP/$_SEVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] Correct Root Directory

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to do things with PHP FTP. I am created the sub domain of the primary domain and the location of primary domain and sub domain are

```
/home/xxx/public_html/.... //primary domain
/home/xxx/sub-domain/...    //sub domain
```

Now, I successfully connected to FTP. But when tried to get the root directory location it is providing:

```
/
```

why it is not providing

```
/home/xxx
```

Now when I tries to change directory location to

```
/home/xxx/sub-domain
```

it shows error as :

```
ftp_chdir() [function.ftp-chdir]: Can't change directory to 
  /home/xxx/sub-domain: No such file or directory
```

Every system as its own directories and sometimes the location is changed to other location as I have seen some times directory root location as:

```
/var/xxx/www
```

How can I make sure to reach the domain/sub-domain root directory correctly

Comment: Can you post some of your PHP?

Comment: Why do you think this is programming related?